# chef fails getting code from a git repository

Tags: chef-infra, knife

I have a private git repo, which I access with the usual SSH keys.
I have a recipe that install the keys (and create the user) on the target machine.
I have created a role in which after that recipe, there is a simple pull from git in order to retrieve the code for that service.
However, in every run this is what I get:

```
Permission denied (publickey).
Could not read from remote repository.
```

This is a simple enough git message claiming that the key is not there, while it is. In order to check it, I log into that newly created machine, and then either ssh git or directly pull the repo in question (or any private one under my account) **using the user name that was configured in the first recipe**. it's working every time. It doesn't work in the role though, although I'm copying the lines one by one.

This includes recipes that used to work, so I suspect that this is the knife version (12.4.1). anyone has an issue like that? is there a way to fix that without rolling back version?

Comment: so you use chef's `git` resource to checkout the code?

Comment: no. just using execute with git command. This works on earlier versions, not in the last one. tested that on 11.? and it was working in all the times I've run it.